# How Set Image URL As Featured Image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have article with title "POST-TITLE" and I create image title same with post title, "POST-TITLE.jpg".

All image I put in my hosting, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/img/CATEGORY/POST-TITLE.jpg
```

In mytheme post-single.php, I have this code:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/img/<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ''; } ?>/<?php the_title(); ?>.jpg" onError="this.src='http://cerpenkoran.net/img/dot.jpg';" title="Thumb for <?php the_title(); ?>" >
```

My answer:

What code I add the image url code above, so it as Featured Image?

OR how to combine this fix URL:

```
http://www.example.com/img/<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ''; } ?>/<?php the_title(); ?>.jpg
```

with this Featuread Image code:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what?.................

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to add a Featured Image to your WordPress website?  If so, then follow the below instructions:

1. Firstly, you are going to need to add the relevant Theme Support inside your `functions.php` file.  To achieve this, go into your `functions.php` file and enter the following code:

   `<?php
       function my_theme_name_support(){
           add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
       }
   add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_name_support');
   ?>`
2. Make sure that the above code is placed after the opening `<?php` tag (at the top of the `functions.php` file) but before the closing `?>` tag (at the bottom of the `functions.php` file.)
3. You will see that there are two `my_theme_name_support` entries.  You can change the wording of these to something more appropriate.  Just make sure they match.
4. Now, head into your WordPress Dashboard and go to create a New Page or New Post.  You should now be able to see an entry, entitled 'Featured Image'.  As you scroll the page, you should see it appear on the right hand side.  Simply select the link and add the required image.
5. This, alone, does not output the Featured Image.  To output your Featured Image, you now need to enter the following code into the relevant file(s) on your server:

   `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>`

By following the above steps, you should now be able to dynamically call your Featured Images from your WordPress Dashboard and output them to whichever pages you want.

For more information, on Featured Images, check out this [WordPress Codex Article >>>](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/)

**Answer Extension**

If you want the **same** image to appear for **every** Blog Post, so that you do not have to manually add a Featured Image to every Blog Post, you could:

1. Upload the image to WordPress, via their Media Uploader.
2. Then head to the `single.php` Blog Post Template File and enter the following code:

   `<img src="POST-TITLE.jpg" alt="post-title" height="42" width="42">`

Be sure to make the following modifications, to the above code:

**src:**  This is the link to the actual image.  Therefore, change 'POST-TITLE.jpg' to the name of your desired image.  Be sure to include the correct image format (.jpg, .png etc).

**alt:**  This is a brief description of the image.  No coding required here.  Plain text will do.

**height and width:**  Insert the correct dimensions.  The dimensions are in pixels.

**Please Note ...**

`single.php` is the default Blog Post Template File.  There is a chance that there are additional Blog Post Template files too.  If this is the case, you will need to add the code to these other Template Files too.

You may find this [WordPress Article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/), helpful, when working with Template Files.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. My question is actually simple. I just want to combine http://www.example.com/img/CATEGORY/POST-TITLE.jpg into this code <?php the_post_thumbnail ('thumbnail'); ?>. So when I create a new post, the image automatically featured image immediately appears because the name of the image is the same as the title of the article.

Comment: So I have understood, you want to have the same 'Featured Image' to be associated with every Blog Post?

Comment: I have just extended my answer, where the detail below 'Answer Extension' should provide the answer you are looking for.